# Why do I keep getting bad index files with Git

Tags: git, hard-drive, corrupt

I keep getting the following error:

```
error: bad index file sha1 signature
fatal: index file corrupt
```

And I know the short term solution is just to delete the index and away you go but my question is, why does it keep happening?

I'm not running any kind of utilities over my repo (that i'm aware of) and the hard drive has plenty of disk space.

Since this has happened twice this week, i'm a little concerned. Could this be a sign of HD failure?

I know the question isn't strictly programming but I figured this is more likely to be something that a fellow programmer has experienced in the past.

Comment: Might it be that you have, mistakenly, instructed, for example, `make` to do things inside your `.git` directory? Do you perform any actions with very permissive recursive globbing that might overwrite the wrong file?

Comment: No, nothing like that. The first time it happened I thought that but the second time was just a home project where nothing else touches the folder.

Comment: It's been quite a while since you've asked this question. Did you find an answer? At work, some of the colleagues have the same problem.

Comment: Afraid not, I actually got a new MBP and haven't had the issue since. The only things that have changed are the hardware and the fact i'm no longer working over a network.